# Sub total is not updating on custom discount (Substraction is not working with dynamic value in cart)

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, discount, totals, update-subtotal

I am working on a module in which I need to develop a discount facility. Everything is working fine, however, when the customer is not logged in at that time gift card discount showing but the base total is not updated.

If I give a static value for a discount, it is working fine. It's also working well on the checkout page, but in the cart page, it works only when logged in customer.

```
/**
 * Gift class 
 */
class Gift extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal
{   
    /**
     * price currency
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface
     */
    protected $_priceCurrency;

    /**
     * checkout session
     *
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    /**
     * fees
     *
     * @var    String
     */
    protected $_fees;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     */ 
    public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession, \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency)
    {
        $this->_checkoutSession=$checkoutSession;
        $this->_priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
        $this->_fees=0;

        if($this->_checkoutSession->getGift()!=''):

            $this->_fees=$this->_checkoutSession->getGift();
        endif;

    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
     * @return $this
     */
    public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ) {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
        $discount =  $this->_fees;
        \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->debug("test");
        \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->debug($discount);
        if($discount){
            /*\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->debug("test");
             \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->debug($discount);*/
            $address             = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
                $label               = 'giftcertificate';
                $discountAmount      = -($discount); 

                $appliedCartDiscount = 0;
                if($total->getDiscountDescription()) {
                    // If a discount exists in cart and another discount is applied, the add both discounts.
                    $appliedCartDiscount = $total->getDiscountAmount();
                    $discountAmount      = $total->getDiscountAmount()+$discountAmount;
                    $label = $total->getDiscountDescription().', '.$label;
                }    

                $total->setDiscountDescription($label);
                $total->setDiscountAmount($discountAmount);
                $total->setBaseDiscountAmount($discountAmount);
                $total->setSubtotalWithDiscount($total->getSubtotal() + $discountAmount);
                $total->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($total->getBaseSubtotal() + $discountAmount);

                $total->setGift($discountAmount);
                $total->setBaseGift($discountAmount);

                $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal() + $discountAmount);
                $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() + $discountAmount);



               if(isset($appliedCartDiscount)) {
                $total->addTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount + $appliedCartDiscount);
                $total->addBaseTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount + $appliedCartDiscount);
            } else {
                $total->addTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount);
                $total->addBaseTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    } 

    /**
     * @param Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $total
     */
    protected function clearValues(Address\Total $total)
    {
        $total->setTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('tax', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('tax', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setSubtotalInclTax(0);
        $total->setBaseSubtotalInclTax(0);
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param Address\Total $total
     * @return array|null
     */
    public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total)
    {

        return [
            'code' => 'giftcertificate',
            'title' => 'giftcertificate',
            'value' => $this->_fees
        ];

    }

    /**
     * Get Subtotal label
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getLabel()
    {
        return __('Gift Card');
    }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I can't understand what's wrong. I need help. Help will be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Is there anyone who can help on this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the $discount value is missing when the customer is not logged in as you fetch the `$discount` value from `$this->_fees;`
and in `_construct()` you have defined

```
if($this->_checkoutSession->getGift()!=''):
       $this->_fees=$this->_checkoutSession->getGift();
endif;
```

So most probably when the customer is not logged in the `getGift` value is null which is why the subtotal value is not getting updated.

Comment: Thanks @mudit, but it show discount in summary however subtraction is not working..

Comment: It works now, actually i needed to override JS Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/grand-total  to update total in cart. I will put solution in answer soon, Thanks @mudit for reply

Comment: @sameer what is the solution ??

Comment: @gajjalasandeep i have updated it as answer. I hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

Override:

`Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/grand-total.js` inside your module

and put your cart discount code inside function getValue:

In my case:

```
getValue: function() {
                var price = 0;
                if (this.totals()) {
                    if(totals.getSegment('grand_total').value!==0){
                        var giftvalue = Math.abs(totals.getSegment('giftcertificate').value);

                        if(totals.getSegment('grand_total').value <  giftvalue){
                            price = totals.getSegment('grand_total').value;     
                        }
                        else{
                            price = totals.getSegment('grand_total').value + totals.getSegment('giftcertificate').value;    
                        }

                    }
                    else{
                        price = totals.getSegment('grand_total').value; 
                    }    

                }
                return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
            },
```

Updated `grand-total.js` in my module:

```
 /**
 * 
 * Overrided
 */
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
    ],
    function (Component, quote, priceUtils, totals) {
        "use strict";
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed: window.checkoutConfig.isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed || false,
                template: 'Magento_Tax/checkout/summary/grand-total'
            },
            totals: quote.getTotals(),
            isTaxDisplayedInGrandTotal: window.checkoutConfig.includeTaxInGrandTotal || false,
            isDisplayed: function() {
                return this.isFullMode();
            },
            getValue: function() {
                var price = 0;
                if (this.totals()) {
                    if(totals.getSegment('grand_total').value!==0){
                        var giftvalue = Math.abs(totals.getSegment('giftcertificate').value);

                        if(totals.getSegment('grand_total').value <  giftvalue){
                            price = totals.getSegment('grand_total').value;     
                        }
                        else{
                            price = totals.getSegment('grand_total').value + totals.getSegment('giftcertificate').value;    
                        }

                    }
                    else{
                        price = totals.getSegment('grand_total').value; 
                    }    

                }
                return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
            },
            getBaseValue: function() {
                var price = 0;
                if (this.totals()) {
                    price = this.totals().base_grand_total;
                }
                return priceUtils.formatPrice(price, quote.getBasePriceFormat());
            },
            getGrandTotalExclTax: function() {

                var totals = this.totals();
                if (!totals) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return this.getFormattedPrice(totals.grand_total);
            },
            isBaseGrandTotalDisplayNeeded: function() {
                var totals = this.totals();
                if (!totals) {
                    return false;
                }
                return totals.base_currency_code != totals.quote_currency_code;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

This worked for me.